# IBM Watson retuning empty response

Tags: php, curl, watson

I have a simpel php Curl call to get something from curl natural languauge understanding.

This is my code:

```
   $report = strtoupper($report);         

$username = 'xxx';
$password = 'xxx';
$url = 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-understanding  /api/v1/analyze?version=2017-02-27&text=Helloethics&features=entities,sentiment,keywords';

// Set post arguments for call
$post_args = array(
    'text' => $report
);//Set header arguments for call
$header_args = array(
    'Content-Type: text/plain',
    'Accept: application/json'
);// Set options for REST call via curl
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "xxx:xxx");        
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header_args);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_args);

$status_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);print_r($status_code);
// Actual REST call via curl and cleanup (closing) of curl call
$result = curl_exec($curl);
echo "print:";print_r($result);
curl_close($curl);
```

But it just brings me an empty respons. What do I do wrong? And how can I fix this?

Comment: Do be aware you have a gap in `$url`.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the extra space in your $url variable is causing problems.

However, if you're sure that's not it, try using `var_dump($result)` instead of `print_r($result)`.

You're accepting JSON data which initially comes back as a string. I think var_dump() will confirm you need to use `$resultArray = json_decode($result, true);` before you can use print_r to display your cURL response.

I'd also recommend adding `<pre></pre>` tags around your output for readability... personal preference though.

If the above solution isn't working, what do you get when you do `var_dump($status_code)`?

TLDR - always use var_dump() to debug, it can save you on more occasions than you expect.